# Inserting a name into a MySql database via an ASP.net web Application

Tags: asp.net, mysql

I am having a problem in inserting characters such as a name into a mySql database via an Asp.net application.

If I inserted numbers, the app adds the numbers into the database and I can see them, but the case with names, the name column in the database shows no values (keeps on showing null values) along with the numbers added.

```
command2 = New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO customer(Customer_id, Customer_name) VALUES (@Customer_id, @Customer_name)", Connection) // Connection String

command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Customer_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = TextBox1.Text()  //assign values

command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Customer_name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text()  //assign values
```

I appreciate it if you can help me with this

Regards,
DoN

Answer (score 0):

Try placing single quotes around `@Customer_name`:

`command2 = New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO customer(Customer_id, Customer_name) VALUES (@Customer_id, '@Customer_name')", Connection) // Connection String`

Comment: Thanx Colin for the reply ... actually what happened is that '@Customer_name' is added into the database as @Customer_name ... even if I wrote some name in Textbox2.text after running the application and pressing the Add button ... it adds it as @Customer_name in the database ..

Comment: Ah okay. I was honestly just making a guess here :P In Drupal, I need to do something similar where I wrap string parameters in single quotes, wasn't sure if it was the same but wanted to throw that idea out there just in case :)